# How can I center the second list item element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-lists

I am trying to learn how to do the swiping menu using `css / scss` from an image I found online [Movies
by Artem Borodynya](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/329319/screenshots/2663131/movies.gif)

So far I have managed to have:

```
<ul class="navbar">
   <li>Menu</li>
   <li class="selected">Actualities</li>
   <li>Substitutions</li>
   <li>Canteen</li>
   <li>Calendar</li>
   <li>Files</li>
</ul>
```

Using some **display: flex** magic I have managed to get it roughly centered, but not perfectly.

The question is, how should I do the menu correctly? Is flex the right thing to use? How can I center the second li element and have others float around it?

I am using this as an experiment and I would like to learn how it should work.

**EDIT:**

my css:

```
.navbar {
    @include flexbox();

    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: flex-end;

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    li {
        list-style: none;
        font-family: 'Roboto Black', sans-serif;
        padding-right: 3rem;

        &.selected {
            font-size: 3em;
            color: #798AC5;
        }

        &:not(.selected) {
            font-size: 2em;
            color: #D9D9DA;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ULs have a default padding applied by the browser, so make sure you reset it, that's probably what's keeping it off-centre

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: post your CSS and we might be able to help

Comment: You should use `align-items: center;` to align the items along the `flex-direction`. As you are using `row`, the items will be aligned to the bottom with `flex-end`. [This link](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv) helps a lot to visualize the behavior of flex properties.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question without posted CSS. Here is something I have created:

```
<ul class="navbar">
   <li>Menu</li>
   <li class="selected">Actualities</li>
   <li>Substitutions</li>
   <li>Canteen</li>
   <li>Calendar</li>
   <li>Files</li>
</ul>

<style>
    ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        list-style: none; /* Remove browser defaults */
        padding-left: 0;  /* Remove browser defaults */
    }

    ul.navbar li:not(:last-of-type) {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    li.selected {
        background-color: rgb(204, 255, 0);
    }
</style>
```

Test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/jwde4ufa/1/